# How is calculated fill-factor percentage related to size of database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, fill-factor

I have rebuilt all indexes in my database setting fill-factor of 95 (5% free space) using a maintenance plan. After the reindex the database is almost doubled in size - reported free space is 42%.

***How is calculated fill-factor related to the size of the database?***

Maybe something is wrong with reindex; what causes so much growth of size?

Some database info after reindex:

```
Size (MB):            164 983.625
Data Space Used (KB):      82 907 896
Index Space Used (KB):     14 073 320
Space Available (KB):      71 879 024
```

Generated T-SQL for maintenance plan for one table:

```sql
ALTER INDEX [Table1_Index1] ON [dbo].[Table1] REBUILD PARTITION = ALL 
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
   IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
   ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95)
```

### Additional informations:

Result of `sp_spaceused 'dbo.BigTable'`

```
name        rows        reserved    data        index_size  unused
BigTable    58028080    72824296 KB 68393936 KB 4424000 KB  6360 KB
```

Comment: What command did you use to get those DB size numbers? Different commands measure different things. Please edit the information directly into the question.

Comment: Do you have a large table with a clustered index? About 120% of that space will be needed during the clustered index rebuild, which will become free space after the operation. That would explain the increase in both database size and freespace after the operation.

Comment: I used SQL Management Studio to read size numbers. One table is very large, about 75% size of database. All tables have clustered PK indexes and many non-clustered.

Comment: Do you have similar database info before reindex? Echoing what @DanGuzman said, when a new index structure is created, disk space for both the old (source) and new (target) structures is required in their appropriate files and filegroups. The old structure is not deallocated until the index creation transaction commits. Once deallocated it shows up as free space.

Comment: Table size numbers after database shrink is essentially the same (differences by few MB).

Comment: @DanGuzman: That 120% of additional space is *data* space or *index* space? It would be weird to duplicate *data* for building new temporary *index*.

Comment: @SylwesterZarębski, with a clustered index, the table is the index so it is the size of the data. The free space needed to rebuild the largest clustered index is the cost of doing business.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see is correct.

When you `rebuild` an `index` first the new `index` is built and only then the old `index` is dropped. And if you don't use

```
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON
```

**the space that server needs to make a `sort` is allocated within your `db`**

Your `db` has now empty space, it's not space `reserved` to any `object`, it's just free space
(space that was freed after temp objects needed to do `sort` were dropped)

So your indexes are not empty on 42%, it's your `db` that is empty on 42% and if you do a`shrink` of `data file` (I don't recommend it) your db will occupy only `82Gb`

Comment: After excluding rebuild of *big table* index, there are no such large growth. Thanks all for helping diagnose this issue.

Answer (score 2):

> How is calculated fill-factor related to the size of the database?

This is due to the fact that the database is accumulated value of following and all their size counted/stored in pages.

1. Heap
2. Clustered Index
3. Non Clustered Index
4. Un-allocated space

In the case fill factor set other than default (0 or 100), every page had to leave the empty space. i.e. a fill factor value 90% lead every page to leave 10% of free space (which already occupied in disk) this cause 10% growth of index and eventually database.

You can get quick details from each table using `sp_spaceused 'dbo.TableName'` or use following query to get details for all tables:

```
select   DB_NAME () AS DBName
        --,OBJECT_NAME (t.object_id) as ObjectName
        --,I.name as IndexName
        ,i.type_desc as UsageType
        ,SUM( (t.lob_used_page_count  * 8.00) / 1024 ) as LOB_Used_Mb
        ,SUM( (t.used_page_count * 8.00) / 1024 ) - SUM( (t.lob_used_page_count  * 8.00) / 1024 ) as Row_Usage_Mb
        ,SUM( (t.used_page_count * 8.00) / 1024 ) as Total_Used_Mb
        ,sum( (t.reserved_page_count * 8.00) / 1024) as Total_Reserved_Mb
        ,sum( ((reserved_page_count - used_page_count) * 8.00) /1024 ) as UnUsed_Mb
from sys.dm_db_partition_stats as T
        join sys.indexes as I on T.object_id = I.object_id and T.index_id = I.index_id
GROUP BY i.type_desc--, OBJECT_NAME (t.object_id), I.name
GO
```

Comment: I've appended additional information about big table. Index do not look like it should be *grown* to dozens of gigabytes, but maybe i'm reading it wrong.

Comment: You probably got to check with the size that were noted before fill-factor changes there must be impact with fill factor, if the variance is not significant. Consider sepupic’s answer and [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d3516f8b-82fe-4e1b-bf3e-64aa6c9a5800/database-size-increase-after-index-rebuild?forum=sqldatabaseengine) as other causes.

Answer (score 1):

> I have rebuilt all indexes in my database setting fill-factor of 95 (5% free space)

This is almost always a bad idea.

How many of those indexes use sequential primary keys?  If any of them do, you are just wasting disk space.

You should only add fill factor space, if and when you have a good reason to.  In most cases unless a index is fragmented > about 30% you would not even rebuild/reorganize it.  Even then you would only consider adding fill factor space if it is getting fragmented fast or often.

I recommend you put the fill factor back to zero, and use the code below to periodically check for fragmented indexes.

If you have a scheduled index job like ola https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html it should include details about what indexes are being rebuilt/reorganized check those results before making any changes.

```
--Check Index Fragmentation (where >30%)

-- Source https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Check-SQL-Server-a-a5758043
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(ind.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName, 
ind.name AS IndexName, indexstats.index_type_desc AS IndexType, 
indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
indexstats.page_count,
indexstats.record_count -- 'SAMPLED' in Scanning Modes gives estimate based on 1% count, NULL gives no results but is fastest query, 'DETAILED' gives actual value but is very slow.
-- Source 'Scanning Modes' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-physical-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#scanning-modes 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SAMPLED') indexstats 
INNER JOIN sys.indexes ind  
ON ind.object_id = indexstats.object_id 
AND ind.index_id = indexstats.index_id 
WHERE indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30 
ORDER BY indexstats.avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

### Additional note:

Many sources do not recommend rebuild/reorganize on indexes with less than 1.000 pages.  Ola's default settings will ignore these.